# facebook error invalid key hash for some devices

Tags: android, facebook, hash

the error is only for devices which have facebook app installed otherwise for the devices which don't have facebook app installed, it's working properly.
And the hash key it is showing is not one which I have saved in developers site of facebook.

I would appreciate any help on this.
 [please refer image for screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrItU.jpg)

Comment: Please add this hash key at developer console

Comment: add hash key in your app.after submit the app this problem solved

Comment: I added the hash key to fb developer console and that solved this problem thanks @ShoebSiddique

Comment: @Bhargav Rao any reason why you delete my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your Hash key to Developer Console of Facebook.

This issue might be happened because of key store.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Android Key hash will change if you build apk from another device(PC). For this you will get another keyhash and add it to developer account.

Facebook allow multiple key. add this key to developer account and everything will work properly.

Comment: Hi, If we want to add different hash key in to fb developer account for different devices. it's very difficult.How can run with one hash key for all devices.

Comment: Its pretty easier upto 5 or lets say 10 device. If more than that then you need to keep one device only for the building APK.

Comment: Hi shabbir, Thanks for reply. I want to send the apk for clients for testing fb login, it's not possible to ask about hash key to the client and set it in to face book developer account. Is there any alternative to do that.

Comment: You dont need to ask hash from client. After build APK upload it to you phone and you come know about hash code. Add that code to fb console and provide apk to client.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am fallowing same patteren, After releasing my app installed in to my phone it's showing invalid hash key error with some hash key.I have added that hash key in to fb developer account it's working fine. When I am install same apk in to another device again getting same issue like invalid hash key error.

Comment: That is weird. Kindly raise it to developer facebook forum https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/ You will surely get help from there.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for support. For releasing mode how can I get that hash key. i.e when push my app in to play store how can I set hash key in to fb developer account.

Answer (score 1):

Please add hash key which is mentioned in Image in developer console. When you use debug hash-key, you need to add that particular hash key in Developer console.

> Please make sure, Any build generated by last PC(Device), that need to
>   Add in Developer console.

Facebook allow multiple hash-keys for that.

Hope it will help you !

Comment: Okay @Mithilesh. Great ! Please accept this answer and upvote if you feel that, it helped you my friend !

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a release key hash for your application using the same keystore you use for generating release signed apk. Most probably, the key you have registered on Facebook Developer Console is your debug key hash and hence a different key is shown to you.

Use this command for linux/mac:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <aliasName> -keystore <keystoreFilePath> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

You'll have to key in your keystore password here.